# Get count of a value in a dataframe column and the value itself into separate lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say this is my frame:

```
   A
0  j
1  j
2  k
3  j
4  b
5  k
```

I am aware of `value_counts()` and `.count()` and `groupby operations`. My issue with those are that they return a series object / i can only really get the count itself out.

What I want to have happen is I want two separate lists (one with the value itself and the other the count) ordered in descending order of frequency like so:

```
ValueList=[j,k,b]
CountList=[3,2,1]
```

I am unsure of how to achieve this using pandas. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Series` index and values to `list`s:

```
s = df.A.value_counts()
ValueList = s.index.tolist()
CountList = s.tolist()
print (ValueList)
['j', 'k', 'b']

print (CountList)
[3, 2, 1]
```